# How to stick div in container when scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

i would like to achive this effect, when user scroll down `#cart` will stick on screen and stay in `div.container` only. Something like below. I try to use position fixed but when scroll down `#cart` cannot stick inside container div. Should i consider jQuery for this effect?

[image]

Html

```
<header>Header</header>
<div id="container">
    <div id="cart">Cart
        <p>1x MacBook Air</p>
        <p>1x iPhone</p>
        <p>1x iPod</p>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

css

```
header {
   width: 400px;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: #ddd;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
#container {
  background-color: #aeaeae;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}
#cart {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
footer {
   width: 400px;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: #ddd;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Demo [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruslyrossi/bsv0tuqq/)

Comment: The position:fixed will only stay put within the page, as you saw. I think jQuery is the best option. I can't think of a way to do it with just CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is either:

[StickyMojo](http://mojotech.github.io/stickymojo/)
or
[jQuery Stickem](https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-Stickem)

Bootstrap has a similar thing, called [Affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix).

Answer (score 0):

`position:fixed` will work. You just need to move the cart div outside the container div.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed positioning is document based so will be fixed to the entire window as the user scrolls. You cannot fixed position AND be inside a container. You'd have to take #cart out to fix it.

To have it so that it sticks inside that container but is also fixed is contradictory.

If you'd like it to stay fixed, but once it hits the bottom of the container as you scrolled down to far so it just touched the bottom of that container and stays inside - thats a jquery job. I can help with this if thats what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You want `position: fixed;` on the `#cart` element, and you'll probably need some Javascript to keep it right aligned with the container.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqrrz0qg/)